# What happens when you write to /dev/null? What’s the point?

Tags: null

Tried `echo "Some text" >> /dev/null`
then `cat null` with no output. Can someone explain why this is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `null` device acts like a black hole. Anything written to it is discarded, and if you try to read from it you receive an end-of-file immediately.

It is used to discard unwanted output and to provide null input.

Without it, it would be very hard to discard unwanted output. Basically, you would have to store the unwanted output in a file that you then deleted, or write a program that consumed all the data without doing anything to it.  Similarly, you would have to create an empty file to provide an immediate end-of-file to processes that you didn't want to, e.g., read from standard input.

The presence of `/dev/null` is mandated by the POSIX standard, and it says that it is...

> An empty data source and infinite data sink. Data written to `/dev/null` shall be discarded. Reads from `/dev/null` shall always return end-of-file (EOF).

It is one of only three devices under `/dev` that needs to be available on a POSIX system. The others are `/dev/tty` and `/dev/console`.

Reference: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm

Comment: I wonder why the '<' operator usually overwrites files but doesn't overwrite /dev/null, despite the fact that you can replace the /dev/null file?

Comment: @Woodstock You mean `>` (not `<`)? It's because `/dev/null` is a device file, not a regular file. You can't replace a device file with a regular file using redirection. The same holds true for a named pipe (created with `mkfifo`). Opening a device for writing to triggers a very different underlying behavior than opening a regular file for writing to.

Comment: thank you very much, Unix is beautiful. You're a gent :+1 upvoted and yep, I meant >!